# Equivalence of sup-norm and norm of coefficients for polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $P=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k$ be a polynomial of degree $n$.
How would you prove that the max of coefficients norm of $P$, i.e.
${\Vert P\Vert}_1=\max_{0\le k\le n}|a_k|$ is smaller than the norm, ${\Vert P\Vert}_2= \sup |P(z)|$ for $z$ belonging to the unit ball?